# Qt - Android work with library fails

Tags: android, c++, qt, libraries

i'm wondering how to work with libraries in qt-androrid.
I've tested to use libs with qt 5.3.2 [suggested here.](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/29592) It is possible to compile but the test app can't start.

```
 qt: 5.3.2; ndk: r10b x64; sdk: 20140702 x64; windows 8.1; api-level: 16;
```

In the *.pro

i've added

```
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
```

and

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/android/libs/ -lmylib
```

i've copied my

```
 *.so     file into   /android/libs
```

(i've also tested to copy the whole lib- projectfolder in /android/libs and added the includepath in the *.pro...)

```
 mylib.h ,*.cpp *_global.h
```

files are now in the Project dir.

I've created the

```
/android/res/values/libs.xml
```

file and added 
    mylib

i've changed the AndroidManifest.xml the line

```
 <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
```

to

```
 <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/my_any_name"/>
```

the result is ok my android-build contains the modified      AndroidManifest.xml     lines as well as the changed      `libs.xml`      lines.

the lib as well as the project were build with armeabi v7a gcc 4.8 Qt 5.3.2

got anyone any idea what's wrong, missing, or how to fix that lib problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the problem exactly, with more details that "the app can't start"? Does it crash, do you have error messages?

Comment: are you able to run a non-qt project with a library? (I suspect your problems are not related to qt)

Comment: it's just not starting. "org.qtproject.example.test" could not be started. for desktop it works fine.. and yes i'm able to start a non-qt project with a lib.

Comment: I'm sorry ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS does the the trick but thx for your time!